# How can I change the :while condition on a Clojure for-loop while it is running?

Tags: for-loop, clojure

I'm searching for the biggest number meeting some condition, out of the set of numbers that are the product of all three-digit numbers.

The straightforward way is this:

```
(apply max (filter 
            my-test? 
            (for [x (range 100 1000)
                  y (range x 1000)]
              (* x y))))
```

But this involves calculating half of all 900*900 products.  If I find, e.g., `(* 380 455)` matches my `my-test?` predicate, I don't need to search any products where either factor is less than 380.  Of course, I will also want to search the list from the biggest to the smallest if I'm doing this.

In psuedo-Clojure, I want to say something like this:

```
(for [x (range 999 99 -1) :while (>= x P)
      y (range x 99 -1) :while (>= y P)]
  (* x y))
```

where `P` is something I magically set to `(min x y)` each time I find a match.

Is there a way to do this in Clojure?

(I realize I could search the numbers in a diagonal fashion, given this specific problem I've set up. However, I'm now trying to solve for the general case of figuring out how to tell the for-loop that some its branches need pruned.)

Comment: From the question and the constraints on the `for` variables I infer that you are trying to solve Project Euler's #4, in which case you want your `for` to return a single result. In this case, why use `for` (which is not a "for" loop but a list comprehension, meant to return a list) over `loop`/`recur` ?

Comment: The right answer is not necessarily the first one I hit.  Although as an exercise for myself I'm going to give `loop`/`recur` a try.

Comment: @omiel is right, this is a much much better way of doing it.  Here is the way that gives a list of candidates that I then need to get the `(max)` of:  (loop [x 999 y 999 min 99 candidates []]
      (cond (<= x min)          candidates 
     (<= y min)          (recur (dec x) 999 min candidates)
     (my-test? (* x y)) (recur x (dec y) (max min y) (conj candidates (* x y)))
     true               (recur x (dec y) min candidates)
     ))

Comment: You should add that as an answer. Also, it's idiomatic to use `:else` as the catch-all for `cond`.

Comment: `If I find, e.g., (* 380 455) matches my my-test? predicate, I don't need to search any products where either factor is less than 380` - this seems completely wrong, if your goal is to find the largest product of two numbers satisfying some predicate. eg, `(* 379 999)` is still larger than `(* 380 455)`. All you can really do is skip pairs where *both* multiplicands are less than 380, in this example.

Answer (score 5):

@omeil suggested a `loop`/`recur` process, and this works *much* better.  `for` loops just aren't built for this.

```
(loop [x 999 y 999 min 99 candidates []]
    (cond (<= x min)          candidates ; exit condition
          (<= y min)          (recur (dec x) 999 min candidates) ; step x
          (my-test? (* x y)) (recur x (dec y) (max min y) (conj candidates (* x y)))
          :else               (recur x (dec y) min candidates) ; step y
     ))
```

Answer (score 1):

A very ugly solution would be to use an `atom`:

```
(let [P (atom 0)]
  (for [x (range 999 99 -1) :while (>= x @P)
        y (range x 99 -1)   :while (>= y @P)]
    (do
      (reset! P (+ x y))
      (* x y))))
```

One thing that I think will get in the way is that the `for` loop doesn't really care what the "output" is, so I am unable to see how it would be able to get that information natively.

The "right" solution is probably a recursive one that allows you to pass in (a.k.a. update) your minimum as you know more.

Comment: This is close to what I had come up with just about a minute after your answer.    I needed to put in a `:when (my-test? (* x y))` to the first argument of the for-loop so that P only gets reset on successful matches.  I agree it doesn't feel very "Clojure-y".